# How to set page size as per text length while printing data using c#

Tags: html, pdf-generation

I have a HTML template which I converted into PDF. All works fine now the issue comes when it converts PDF & only 1-2 lines shows in second page. So what I need if only 1-2 lines comes on second page then it prints entire data in single page.

Any guidance, suggestions really appreciated.

Comment: There are certain CSS elements that control this. I would suggest you invest in a decent tool like PrinceXML for this. It is far superior that what any browser can do.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer that's why we have preview functionality where we can fix these types of stuff but the problem is that my manager is told me he needs this kind of functionality. If there is any way then please let me know. I'm using express PDF.